# Evaluating boolean expression referencing external data

Tags: c#, string, boolean, game-development, evaluate

I've been working on implementing dialogue system with UI editor (Unity & C#), some dialogue options can only be shown to player if certain conditions are met. So far conditions are stored as list of strings (example of condition is "playerHasArmor"), and are checked via Conditions.Contains("playerHasArmor"). However, it doesn't support more complex conditions, such as ("playerHasArmor" && !"armorIsBroken").

How could one implement evaluation of such conditions from one input string? Is writing own evaluator/parser an only option?

DataTables allow evaluating something like "true and false or true", but is it possible to "include" a check like Conditions.Contains(...)?

Comment: Does your code understand `"playerHasArmor"`. If so, put the code in a method (say `bool Verify(string assertion)`). Now you can pass one of your strings, get a bool and `if` to your hearts content. Otherwise, create a bunch of types, and implement the relationships between them. If you do that, you can still parse strings, and with a little Reflection parse those relationships. If you want to go whole hog, take a look at *Antlr*

Comment: I actually have a `bool` method which verifies whether condition is met or not, if condition is simply string, not the "condition1 & condition2". The problem is parsing something like that, so I don't quite see what you suggested in first option. 
Thanks, I'll look into **Antlr**, seems like more solid path to solution.

Comment: What I meant was, assuming you have a method like `Verify`, is that you could say `if (Verify ("playerHasArmor") && !Verify ("armorIsBroken)) { ...}`.  But, you could do that by reading a simple set of strings and interpreting it.  Say the string said `$(playerHasArmor) AND NOT $(armorIsBroken)`, you could parse a string like that and with some simple logic, build code that approproximates the `if` statement.  Antlr is pretty cool though.  Get the O'Rielly book if it's still available